# Default time value through v-model not updating on vue2-datepicker

Tags: vue.js, datetimepicker

I am using vue2-datepicker

```
    <date-picker
        type="time" id="start"
        :time-picker-options="startTimeOptions"
        v-model="start"
        value-type="time"
        format="hh:mm A"
    ></date-picker>
```

and here's the start and startTimeOptions :

```
startTimeOptions:{start: '00:00',step: '00:15',end: '23:45',format: 'hh:mm A'},
start:'12:00' //(also tried with start:'12:00 AM' & start:{hh:'12',mm:'00',A : 'AM'})
```

But none of the above helps to update the value.
At the same time after selecting time on the input, I could see the below value.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changing the value type it works.

`value-type="hh:mm A"`